# Cannot assign object of type "Text" to property of type "QString" as the former is neither the same as the latter nor a sub-class of it

Tags: qt, qml

I have this QML code for a button:

```
RowLayout {

    width: // ...
    height: // ...
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    StyledButton {
        width: 200
        horizontalMargins: 8
        margins: 8
        text: Text { // => error is related to this line
            id: myButton_text
            text: qsTr("A relatively long text here")
        }
        onButtonClicked: {
            console.log("Applying button")
        }
        iconSource: "images/apply_button.png"
        Component.onCompleted: {
            width = myButton_text.paintedWidth + 24
        }
    }

}
```

I receive this error at the above-specified line:

> Cannot assign object of type "Text" to property of type "QString" as the former is neither the same as the latter nor a sub-class of it.

Does anybody know what the cause is?

Comment: change to `text: qsTr("A relatively long text here")`. You should not and cannot assign a Text item to a property that requires a string

Comment: @eyllanesc I need `Text` with ID of `myButton_text` to have access to `myButton_text.paintedWidth`

Comment: mmm, explain yourself better. Why do you need that? I think you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), besides the item `StyledButton` is not a standard item, so if you want help you must provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

Its because the text property of stylebutton is expecting a string, while you provided it with a QQuickTextItem (Text component).

```
RowLayout {

    width: // ...
    height: // ...
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    StyledButton {
        width: 200
        horizontalMargins: 8
        margins: 

        /* text property only accepts strings */
        text: qsTr("A relatively long text here")


        onButtonClicked: {
            console.log("Applying button")
        }
        iconSource: "images/apply_button.png"
        Component.onCompleted: {
            width = myButton_text.paintedWidth + 24
        }
    }

}
```

Styling buttons is done differently in QML.. specifically by using the `contentItem` property for customizing the entire button (see example)

```
  import QtQuick 2.12
  import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

  Button {
      id: control
      text: qsTr("Button")

      contentItem: Text {
          text: control.text
          font: control.font
          opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
          color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
          horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
          verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
          elide: Text.ElideRight
      }

      background: Rectangle {
          implicitWidth: 100
          implicitHeight: 40
          opacity: enabled ? 1 : 0.3
          border.color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
          border.width: 1
          radius: 2
      }
  }
```